# Xcode: Why can't change X, Y values in IB Size Inspector

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I want to change the X,Y values in the Interface Builder Size Inspector, but the values are greyed out, and I can't change them. Why?

Am running Xcode 5.[image]

I have attached a .jpeg to show my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because the ImageView is the main view of the view controller.  Instead, add another view to become the main view and make the ImageView its subview.